# my mongod sever is not working, showing shutter down with code:100

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

Data directory /data/db not found., terminating
2020-05-01T23:50:44.673+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2020-05-01T23:50:44.673+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100

Comment: What is your operating system? Windows or Linux, or Mac?

Comment: `/data/db` doesn't exist. You need to create it.